# Почему проходит компиляцию код, где unowned-property является optional?

Tags: swift

Если unowned свойства в Swift не могут содержать nil, почему проходит компиляцию код, где unowned-property является optional? В чем смысл?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unowned могут содержать nil, быть optional. Если Вы передадите изначально в переменную class2 nil и попытаетесь с ней работать - ничего страшного не произойдет. Но если изначально передать какой не nil объект, работать с ним, а затем он станет nil и продолжить его использовать - вот тогда получите краш.

unowned не запрещает быть optional - это механизм, чтобы "разорвать" retain cycle, гарантирующий что объект на который он указывает (но не держит сильной ссылкой) существует, иначе получим краш.

Такой пример пришел в голову, Ваш класс1 - вышка для прыжков с нее в unowned бассейн с водой. Бассейн существует - прыжки проходят нормально, все налажено. Но затем этот бассейн цементируют и делают из него площадку под застройку, теперь он nil. А вышка для прыжков в бассейн. Очередной прыжок с вышки и... crash программы.

Т.е Ваша забота использовать unowned когда уверены, что время жизни этого class2 извне больше, чем class1 в который Вы его передали.